# Why are there 2 methods for edit and 2 methods for create in MVC Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just get some MVC application from friend to help him about that little bit, but this is my first time I am working with MVC, I've been working with c# allready for over 1 year but never before on `ASP.NET MVC`.

My question is next, when I opened his `controller` which is being used for Editing and Adding new USER, I saw there are 2 methods for EDIT, and two methods for CREATE, and I'm confused why it is like that, here is the code for Create methods only:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
        {

            var model = new UserTypeNew()
            {
                Roles = new List<user_userroles>()
            };


            List<roles> allRoles = RolesController.SelectAll();

            foreach (var item in allRoles)
            {
                user_userroles tempName = new user_userroles()
                {
                    RoleID = item.RoleID,
                    roles = item
                };
                model.Roles.Add(tempName);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

But after while there is again CreateUser method, and I'm confused why? I can't see purpose of each of them.. I can see they are different but could someone explain me why is this like that, what he wanted to achieve (unfortunatelly he is not available right now so I can not speak with him about this piece of code).

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateUser(User model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                database_user newUser = new database_user()
                {
                   UserName=model.UserName,
                   FirstName=model.FirstName,
                   LastName=model.LastName

                };
                UserController.InsertNewUser(newUser);

                // I deleted code about adding roles


                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");

            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

I can notice difference instead of code, there is `[HttpPost]` above second method, and I'm really wondering why are they so different? and why two of them with same name?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one without `HttpPost` is for a GET request. That's when the user navigates to that page. It returns a view, probably containing a form for the user to fill out.

The one with `HttpPost` is for when the user submits the form on the page. It will post to the same URL, but the HTTP method will be different (POST), so it will be routed to the action method marked with the `HttpPost` attribute.

They do not *have* to be the same name. You could name them different. In an application I used to work on, our GET method would be `Edit` and our POST method would be `Update` for example.

Comment: if they were different name, should anything be changed in CreateUser.chhtml View or it doesn't matter?

Comment: The form post needs to have the correct name of the ActionMethod that it should post to, assuming you're using the `@Html.BeginForm` method. Otherwise it'll need to have the correct URL to post to if you just did it with `<form>` tags.